# Install mariadb 5.5 in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, mariadb

I need to install mariadb 5.5 because I have old databases that wouldn't work with mariadb 10 and cause mysql to crash! 
I tried adding this repo but no luck

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu trusty main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mariadb.list'
```

Do you know how to do it?

I tried searching after adding the repo, here's what I got

```
sudo apt search mariadb-server

mariadb-server/focal,focal 1:10.3.22-1ubuntu1 all
  MariaDB database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)

mariadb-server-10.3/focal,now 1:10.3.22-1ubuntu1 amd64 [residual-config]
  MariaDB database server binaries

mariadb-server-core-10.3/focal 1:10.3.22-1ubuntu1 amd64
  MariaDB database core server files
```

Comment: Did you mean `sudo su -c` instead of `sudo sh -c`?

Comment: I copied it like that! I tried your suggestion but when I `sudo apt search mariadb-server` I don't get version 5

Comment: By default `apt` will use the latest version of the package from whichever repo the latest version is in. If you want version 5 you'll have to specify it on the command-line with `sudo apt install mariadb-server=<version>` (replace `<version>` with the version you want). Might be hard to find especially since Ubuntu usually appends stuff to the end of the release numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu trusty main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mariadb.list"
```

As opposed of that, you can feed the input to `tee` rather than `echo` directly to the file.

```
echo "deb http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu trusty main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mariadb.list
```

I think it's more cleaner and give you the output, but if you would like to surpress it— you can always append `> /dev/null` to the end.

---

The command did same thing as adding repository via `add-apt-repository`, so to preserve the change you have to update the index as well.

```
sudo apt update
```